# Column wise sum and comma separated row ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following data in one of my table in SQL Server:

```
Id     Dealer                       Region  Comission
-----------------------------------------------------
177    Synergy Meditech             North   217500.00
1      Indian Orthocare Surgicals   South     1500.00
9      Indian Orthocare Surgicals   South     1500.00
90     Indian Orthocare Surgicals   West      9760.73
113    Indian Orthocare Surgicals   West     39756.90
171    Innovative Concepts          South   127500.00
172    Innovative Concepts          South   142500.00
191    MIDMED HEALTHCARE            North   427500.00
198    MIDMED HEALTHCARE            North   199500.00
185    Cass Associates              West    337500.00
```

The output that I want from the above is:

```
Id               Dealer                       Region  Comission
----------------------------------------------------------------    
177              Synergy Meditech             North   217500.00
1,9              Indian Orthocare Surgicals   South     3000.00
90,113           Indian Orthocare Surgicals   West     49517.63
171,172          Innovative Concepts          South   270000.00
191,198          MIDMED HEALTHCARE            North   627000.00
185              Cass Associates              West    337500.00
```

i.e, the sum of column `commission` on grouping of `Dealer` and `Region`, and also comma-separated Ids.

Please help me with this.

Comment: what is the version of `SQL Server` you are using ?

Comment: sql server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rolled it into one statement:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(Id int, Dealer varchar(50),  Region varchar(20),  Comission decimal(10,2))

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(177,'Synergy Meditech',' North',217500.00)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(1,'Indian Orthocare Surgicals','South',1500.00)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(9,'Indian Orthocare Surgicals','South',1500.00)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(90,'Indian Orthocare Surgicals','West',9760.73)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(113,'Indian Orthocare Surgicals','West',39756.90)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(171,'Innovative Concepts','South',127500.00)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(172,'Innovative Concepts','South',142500.00)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(191,'MIDMED HEALTHCARE','North',427500.00)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(198,'MIDMED HEALTHCARE','North',199500.00)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(185,'Cass Associates','West',337500.00)


SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + CAST(ID as varchar(5))
            FROM #tmp t1 where t2.Dealer = t1.Dealer and t1.Region = t2.Region
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, ''), Dealer,Region,SUM(t2.Comission) Comission  
FROM #tmp t2
GROUP by  Dealer,Region
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select string_agg(id, ',') within group (order by id) as ids,
       dealer, region, sum(commission) as commission
from t
group by dealer, region;
```

In earlier versions:

```
select stuff( (select concat(',', t2.id)
               from t t2
               where t2.dealer = dr.dealer and t2.region = dr.region
               order by t2.id
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as ids
       dr.*
from (select dealer, region, sum(commission) as commission
      from t
      group by dealer, region
     ) dr;
```

The `id`s appear to be numbers, so you don't have to worry about special characters.

Comment: it is giving an error "'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name."

I think "string_agg" is not available in the version i am using

Comment: `select stuff( (select concat(',', t2.id)
               from t t2
               where t2.dealer = t.dealer and t2.region = t.region
               order by t2.id
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as ids,
       dr.*
from (select dealer, region, sum(commission) as commission
      from t
      group by dealer, region
     ) dr;`

it's showing an error:

**The multi-part identifier "t.dealer" could not be bound.**